# how to specify global variables to ignore when minifying with esbuild

Tags: javascript, html, bundling-and-minification, esbuild

I'm working on a webpage has js files that don't provide esm exports, and they define global variables that other files depend on. Something like this:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
...
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
...
```

```js
/* first.js */
var someGlobalVariable = 'value';

/* second.js */
function anImportantFunc() {
  doSomethingWith(someGlobalVariable);
}
...
anImportantFunc();
```

The webpage does not use any UI framework.

I'm trying to minify these js files but the minifier understandably changes the names of the global variables without updating the other files that depend on them, so those other files throw errors when they hit undefined variables. Is there a way to make the minifier aware of this, possibly by specifying variables to ignore in some/all files? Similar to how eslint allows you to specify globals that shouldn't be marked as undefined. I understand this may be difficult because the files don't have clear dependency tree relationships in the way that modules have. I'm using [`esbuild`](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild) but open to other build tools if they handle this scenario well. Thanks.

Comment: The esbuild documentation seems to indicate it won't do this by default unless you specify bundling.

Comment: Even with bundling specified it doesn't do it. Someone suggested that I have to concatenate the files first, but it seems esbuild doesn't have that functionality either.

Comment: Can't you (unnecessarily) export these global variables? Exported symbols should be preserved after minification.